# Using regex in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a text file which contains some lines this

```
something1 1.2 MB
something2 5.3 MB
```

I want to remove (X.X MB), so I did this in notepad++

find what   :  `*.*[ MB]`

replace with:

Regular expression

But it says invalid regular expression. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try:

Find:

```
 \d*\.\d* MB
```

(yes, there's a space before the first `\d`).

Replace with nothing.

`\d` stands for a digit in regex, and you need to escape the dot since the dot is a wildcard in regex. `*` is an operator and means 0 or more times. The square brackets is a character class and would otherwise match any one of space, M or B. Just remove them here.